# How to evaluate integration limits for path/line integral for an advection flux problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fluid-dynamics

The following path integral arises as a 2D fluid dynamics problem when evaluating the advective flux of a concentration $C(x,y)$ by the 2D velocity field $[u(x,y),v(x,y)]$ across a path between $s_1=[x_1,y_1]$ and $s_2=[x_2,y_2]$ with a layer depth $H(x,y)$:

$$flux=\int_{s_1}^{s_2}C(x,y)H(x,y)[u(x,y),v(x,y)]\cdot\hat{\textbf{n}}\cdot ds$$ where $\hat{\textbf{n}}$ is the unit vector normal to the segment $s$.

Solving this the "right" way by parameterizing $x$ and $y$ using $s$ produces ungainly results, but it occurred to me that using:

$$ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$$ and $$\hat{\textbf{n}}=\frac{[-dy,dx]}{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}$$
reduces this to:

$$flux=-\int_{s_1}^{s_2}C(x,y)H(x,y)u(x,y)\cdot dy + \int_{s_1}^{s_2}C(x,y)H(x,y)v(x,y)\cdot dx$$

Can I somehow use this trick? If so, how would I evaluate the integration limits for the two definite integrals in terms of $(x,y)$? Note that both integrals contain a non-integrating variable that cannot be assumed constant.

Comment: I think this is as complete as you can get for the flux, unless you have a specific $C(x,y), H(x,y), u(x,y)$ in mind.

Comment: My question concerns how to evaluate the integration limits.  If there were path-independence, then I could evaluate the $dx$ integral from $x_1$ to $x_2$ while holding $y$ constant at $y=y_1$ and the $dy$ integral from $y_1$ to $y_2$ with $x$ constant at $x=x_2$, but I do not see how this integral is path-independent.